# Unknown web-method, trying to send json using AJAX

Tags: c#, json, ajax

I'm trying to pass some data (parameter) from client side (html) to the server side (C# code-behind) to a method, this is done using AJAX in JSON format, but I'm getting the following error:

> Unknown Web Method

my AJAX code is:

```
var jsonObj = { "sCriterion": sCriterion };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "NewToken.aspx/GetSelection",
                data: jsonObj,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest) + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(data);
                    alert("We returned: " + result);
                }
            });
```

and this is my code-behind method:

```
[WebMethod]
private static string GetSelection(string selectedItem)
{

    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var data = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>[]>(selectedItem.ToString());
    var jsonObj = json.Serialize("proceeded");
    return jsonObj;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method should be `public static` to work. Not private !

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetSelection(string selectedItem)
{

    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var data = json.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>[]>(selectedItem.ToString());
    var jsonObj = json.Serialize("proceeded");
    return jsonObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetSelection` method must be `public`, but you set it private.